# wrong sorting in index (ligatures) \/

Tags: indexing, sorting, ligatures

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

% No \/
%\index{final position}
%\index{fixed part}
%\index{flow chart}
%\index{feedback}

% With \/
\index{f\/inal position}
\index{f\/ixed part}
\index{f\/low chart}
\index{feedback}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Display, no \ /; (true sorting)

[image]

Display, with \ /; (wrong sorting)

[image]

I didn't find duplicate another question. So, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: you will need something like `\index{f\/ixed part@fixed part}` to supply an alphabetic sort string, or some other letter than `@` as specified in your makeindex style.

Comment: @David, I am checking.

Comment: `\index{sortkey@actualkey}`; so `\index{fixed part@f\/ixed part}`.

Comment: @Özgür sorry I got them in the wrong order, see egreg's correction

Comment: @egreg, it works perfect. CLOSED.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

makeindex can only sort alphabetic entries, so if you need to add markup to the typeset form (`\/` here) then you need to supply a separate sort key, so the entries need to be something like:

```
\index{fixed part@f\/ixed part}
```

`@` is the default character but if you need `@`  in the actual strings you can specify any other separator in your makeindex style.